# Regex or other method for returning these values (from BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

With a great deal of help from the stackoverflow community I am learning a lot about python and specifically scraping with BeautifulSoup. I am referring again to the same example page I am using to learn my way through this.

I have the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

f = open('webpage.txt', 'r')
g = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(g)

for heading in soup.find_all("td", class_="paraheading"):
    key = " ".join(heading.text.split()).rstrip(":")
    if key in columns:
        print key
        next_td = heading.find_next_sibling("td", class_="bodytext")
        value = " ".join(next_td.text.split())
        print value
    if key == "Industry Categories":
        print key
        ic_next_td = heading.find_next_sibling("td", class_="bodytext")
        print ic_next_td
```

which from this page:

```
http://www.aidn.org.au/Industry-ViewCompany.asp?CID=3113
```

saved as webpage.txt gives me the following result:

```
ACN
007 350 807
ABN
71 007 350 807
Annual Turnover
$5M - $10M
Number of Employees
6-10
QA
ISO9001-2008, AS9120B,
Export Percentage
5 %
Industry Categories
<td class="bodytext">Aerospace<br/>Land (Vehicles, etc)<br/>Logistics<br/>Marine<br/>Procurement<br/></td>
Company Email
lisa@aerospacematerials.com.au
Company Website
http://www.aerospacematerials.com.au
Office
2/6 Ovata Drive Tullamarine VIC 3043
Post
PO Box 188 TullamarineVIC 3043
Phone
+61.3. 9464 4455
Fax
+61.3. 9464 4422
```

so far, so good. Will look at writing this to a CSV or something later, but for now I am wondering how to break out the data contained in `<td class="bodytext">Aerospace<br/>Land (Vehicles, etc)<br/>Logistics<br/>Marine<br/>Procurement<br/></td>` to separate lines?

Like this:

```
Industry Categories
Aerospace
Land (Vehicles, etc)
Logistics
Marine
Procurement
```

I have tried a bit of regex such as:

```
if key == "Industry Categories":
        print key
        ic_next_td = heading.find_next_sibling("td", class_="bodytext")
        value = re.findall('\>(.*?)\<', ic_next_td)
        print value[0]
```

But I get the eroor `TypeError: expected string or buffer`. Am thinking I need to iterate over the findall or something too.

The method needs to be general enough to handle other variations in the same format, such as 'Donkey' or 'Boat' instead of 'Aerospace' or 'Logistics' (i will not necessarily know all the possibilities up front in the scenario I am thinking about).

Is there a way to pull this out using the br tag and Beautiful soup, or a regex?

Sorry this is a bit long. As always, also very happy for any suggested code optimisations as well so I can continue to learn the best way to build Python scripts correctly.

Thank you!

**Update**

This code worked:

```
for heading in soup.find_all("td", class_="paraheading"):
    key = " ".join(heading.text.split()).rstrip(":")
    if key in columns:
        print key
        next_td = heading.find_next_sibling("td", class_="bodytext")
        value = " ".join(next_td.text.split())
        print value
    if key == "Industry Categories":
        print key
        ic_next_td = heading.find_next_sibling("td", class_="bodytext")
        for value in ic_next_td.strings:
                print value
```

and this code produced an indentation error:

```
for heading in soup.find_all("td", class_="paraheading"):
    key = " ".join(heading.text.split()).rstrip(":")
    if key in columns:
        print key
        next_td = heading.find_next_sibling("td", class_="bodytext")
        value = " ".join(next_td.text.split())
        print value
    if key == "Industry Categories":
        print key
        ic_next_td = heading.find_next_sibling("td", class_="bodytext")
        for value in ic_next_td.strings:
            print value
```

note seemingly double indentation of `print value` in working code. Seemed to me the next level of indentation would be a single indent after `for value in ic_next_td.strings:`?

Comment: You could split by `"<br/>"` to get each value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to parse out the contents of `ic_next_td` a little further. Luckily, the original page uses `<br/>` tags to give you places to delimit the text. Don't bother with a regex here, BeautifulSoup has better tools for you:

```
for value in ic_next_td.strings:
    print value
```

would result in:

```
Aerospace
Land (Vehicles, etc)
Logistics
Marine
Procurement
```

You can store all these in a list by calling `list()` on the [`.strings` iterator](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings):

```
values = list(ic_next_td.strings)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @MartijnPieters! I knew there had to be a nifty BeautifulSoup method I had overlooked. One follow up question, when integrating this code into my existing code, why do I have to essentially double indent the `print value' otherwise I get an indentation error? If this is not a clear question, I will update op to show more clearly.

Comment: @FusilliJerry: Because the `print` is part of the `for .. in ..:` loop. Everything indented one level deeper than the `for` statement is part of the suite of lines that will be executed for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks. Any chance you could outline a little how the .strings method works here? The documentation is a little light on this subject for my needs (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings). Does it try to break up the text within the reference using a consistent tag? Does it work for tags other than br for example? Thanks @MartijnPieters.

Comment: was still slightly confused actually. Have updated my op with an example of indentation that worked and one that didn't work (which was more intuitive to me) to see if I can get some clarity :) Thanks again

Comment: @FusilliJerry: In XML / HTML parsing, everything is a node, and text is contained in nodes too, but so are the other tags. The `.strings` generator gives you all discreet text nodes. So the text `Aerospace` is in one text node, because you can't have `Aerospace` and `Land (Vehicles, etc.)` in one node because there is a `<br/>` in the middle. It works for nesting too, though, so `<td><b>text</b>other text</td>` would give you `text` then `other text`.

Comment: @FusilliJerry: If you have *different* questions, make a new post (after searching for dupes first). Let's keep focused on one issue at a time.

Comment: Good idea - makes sense. Will do so.

Comment: Great comment explaining the `.strings` generator +1 (IMHO that should be in the answer for future reference)

Comment: @FusilliJerry: as for your indentation 'trouble': You are mixing tabs and spaces. Configure your editor to use spaces *only* and convert any tabs to spaces before you continue.